# Procedure code unavailable for the graph algorithm book?

Tags: neo4j

I am reading the "Graph Algorithms" practical Examples. When I run the following code:

```
CALL algo.closeness.stream("User", "FOLLOWS") YIELD nodeId, centrality
RETURN algo.getNodeById(nodeId).id, centrality ORDER BY centrality DESC
```

It reports an error:

```
There is no procedure with the name `algo.closeness.stream` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.
```

I am new to 'CALL' function. How to get this procedure available in Neo4j Desktop. I downloaded the latest version of the desktop. Do I need to install additionally software?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Graph Algorithms from the plugins tab? Try this, it should make the procedure available to you.